# What determines who "marked" a question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I flagged *[Sort Array Alphabetically (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905501/sort-array-alphabetically-c)* as a duplicate:

[image]

Coming back today and seeing that flag marked helpful, I checked out the question. It has been made a duplicate of the question I flagged as a duplicate, however I am not one of the users listed as "marking" it a duplicate.

I remember being the second person to flag and there's only a 6-hour difference in flag time to duplicate time, so it seems unlikely my vote was too late to be counted, or so early it expired.

Could this happen if my flag was marked "helpful" before the question was actually marked duplicate?

This question is less about my specific scenario and a more general "how are the 'markers' of a duplicate determined?", as my curiosity has been piqued.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The banner shows the people that voted to close the question, not the people that flagged the post for people with the close vote privilege to review.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense, I had been thinking enough dupe flags auto-closed it as a duplicate. I forgot duplicates were part of the whole close-queue.